# french canadian keyboard sublime text 2 shortcut

Tags: sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I have a french canadian keyboard on my mac and I can't find a solution to make work the default shortcut in sublime text 2.

Few times, by mistake, I have make work the shortcut for comment a line but I don't remember the keyboard shortcut I do... :\

How I can fix my problem?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all predefined and user defined shortcuts under

`Preferences > Key Bindings - Default`

`Preferences > Key Bindings - User`

When you need to add a shortcut or change one which defined in Default just copy related line to `Key Bindings - User`  also check Json syntax which sublime uses for configurations. I haven't any idea what changes in french canadian keyboard but I hope it would solves your problem.

**Independent from keyboard, Sublime says :**

`⌘ + /  Comment/un-comment current line`

`⌘ + ⌥ + /  Block comment current selection`

**Updated :**

Default Shortcut List : http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_osx.html